# I need the little blinking cursor inside the input element to be started it from right instead from left

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input element inside the element there is little cursor that's blinking so how do I make the cursor appear from right when the user clicks it,
I am creating a calculator please don't use Jquery plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dir` attribute on the `input`:

```
<input type="text" dir="rtl">
```

RTL means right to left.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries @AliayubAli, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Text Align

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="right" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<input style="text-align: right">
```

rtl attribute, as @Jack mentions, is intended for Arabic texts and may act non-intuitively for left-to-right languages (i.e. backspace key behavior).